# When mouseover one Div it changes the class of another Div on the page using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have one Div "red" that on mouseover I want it to change the class of another Div "blue" on the page to "green".

These 2 divs are contained within different divs them selves see below, can this be done using CSS? if not how can it be done with jquery?

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="red">red</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
    <div id="three">
        <div class="blue">blue</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank You.

Comment: did you used jquery or javascript ?

Comment: It cannot be done with CSS, as in CSS there is no way to transverse up the parent and to its siblings. However, this is doable in jQuery. Also, it is probably not a very good idea to name classes after the appearance of the items - what if, say, you change the background or text colour of `.blue` to something else? It will lose its meaning and context.

Comment: not possible in CSS.You can achieve this easily with jquery

Comment: There is no need to be fixated on the names of the IDs Terry it was only for this example to save confusion for the people reading.  I did expect it would need jquery at time of posting (thats why jquery was tagged).  This was just a question of can it be done See below for the solution in jquery it worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#red').hover(function() {
$('#blue').addClass('.whatever')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, If I have 2 of these functions how do I flick from one to the other if you see you can only preform the function once: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7R3Dj/

Comment: You'll have to explain a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$('#red').on('mouseover', function() {
$('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass("green");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, If I have 2 of these functions how do I flick from one to the other if you see you can only preform the function once: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7R3Dj/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this using Javascript. When the document loads, have some code that has a Hover on one div, then changes the other.

Try This:

```
$("#red").hover(function() {
  $("#blue").addClass("SOMECLASSHERE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with CSS, as in CSS there is no way to transverse up the parent and to its siblings. However, this is doable in jQuery. Also, it is probably not a very good idea to name classes after the appearance of the items - what if, say, you change the background or text colour of .blue to something else? It will lose its meaning and context.

There is, however, a jQuery-based solution that is possible (see p[roof-of-concept fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7R3Dj/))

```
$('#red').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass("green");
});
```

If you want to toggle a class though, you should use this:

```
$('#red').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass("green");
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.green').removeClass('green').addClass('blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Javascript to do this, you can't change the class of a DIV using only CSS, however, you can apply CSS changes to a div on hover of another div which might have the same effect you're going for, however it is not compatible across all browsers.

```
#one:hover #two#three.blue {color: green}
```